# Never got result from wait Task async on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I'm using this code in my windows phone 8 app and I never get a return from this method:

```
private static ObservableCollection<Product> _productList = null;
        public ObservableCollection<Product> GetProductList()
        {
            LoadProducts().Wait();
            return _productList;
        }

        public Product GetProductById(int id)
        {
            return _productList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
        }

        private static async Task LoadProducts()
        {
            _productList = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:15017/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                //HERE I NEVER GET THE RESPONSE 
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products").ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var products = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Product>>();
                    foreach (var product in products)
                    {
                        _productList.Add(new Product(){Description = product.Description, Id=product.Id, Name = product.Name});
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Can someone please tell me why is it like that? I run this method from my ViewModel class to load data

Using @Stephen Cleary sollution http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx there is a problem:

In my View I have set:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource.Result}"
```

Then in codeBehind:

```
this.DataContext = new ProductViewModel();
```

Then in ProductViewModel:

```
public AsyncTaskManager<ObservableCollection<Product>> DataSource { get; private set; }
```

AND:

```
this.DataSource = new AsyncTaskManager<ObservableCollection<Product>>(ProductRepository.LoadProducts());
```

And In AsyncTaskManager PropertyChanged is always null :(

Comment: Try placing a try catch inside that way you can notice if a exception occurs, also i don't think you need ConfigureAwait.

Comment: What Do You mean by COnfigureAwait ? If I dont do this the result list is empty in my View

Comment: Well i can't explain why you get a empty list, but the times i have done async .net coding i never used ConfigureAwait... Have you Tried to open "http://localhost:15017/api/products" in your web browser just to verify that you get the correct result.

Comment: Yes and it works, also using the same code in console app works, and I dont get empty list, I never get the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Wait` in your code is causing a deadlock issue that I describe in detail [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) an [in an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). In short, `await` by default will capture a "context" (in this case, the UI context), and will resume the `async` method in that context. However, when you block the UI thread by calling `Wait`, then the UI thread cannot complete the `async` method it's waiting for. Hence, deadlock.

Since you're using MVVM, I recommend you take a look at my MSDN article on [asynchronous data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx). In summary, you'll need to first design what the view should look like *without* the data and show that, and then *update* the view when the data arrives.

Comment: I used Your code in my solution but in NotifyTaskCompletion PropertyChanged is always null (

Comment: NotifyTaskCompletion was intended to be used with data binding. If `PropertyChanged` is `null`, then the data binding wasn't ever hooked up. Check the output window in the debugger for data binding errors.

Comment: It is really hard to understand code in comments; please post another question with a minimal repro.

Comment: Could You please take a look at the question which I edited according to Your solutiion ?

Comment: @ Stephen Cleary I posted question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090359/patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding

Answer (score 0):

Your emulator cannot bind to `localhost` it must be an ip address of your pc.
That's the problem

Comment: after changing to ip didnt work as well so it might be only part of the problem, but still its a second bug i think

Comment: can you call the service from your pc using the ip address?

Comment: no, its not an issue, but i voted up your answer cause it can be another bug in my code but it isnt the main issue which im talkig about